# Slack channels created using Slack API (and bot token) not showing up after posting a message to it

Tags: slack, slack-api

I created several Slack channels using the Slack API and Bot Token, all necessary permissions are enabled. I am able to create the channels and send message to it successfully. Now the issue is, the channel doesn't show up automatically in the Slack channels list, but when I browse the channel manually, I can see the posted messages.

I'm using the Slack `conversations.create` and `chat.postMessage` API methods. I've also tried using `conversations.list`, `conversations.join`, `conversations.open` but the channel is not showing up yet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After in-depth investigation with the API, I was able to show the created channels on the Channels list.

**[Option 1]**

- If you create the channel with `conversations.create` and Bot Token, you have to use User Token when calling `conversations.join` API method.

**[Option 2]**

- You may decide to use just `user token` and call the `conversations.create` and `conversations.join` API methods.

**[Option 3]**

- If you create the channel using `conversations.create` API method and a `user token`, you don't need to call `conversations.join` to join the channel if you have `channels:read` (public channel) or `groups:read` (private channel) permission enabled, the channel will become visible on the Slack Channels list.

Looks like only a `User Token` can be used to add a Slack channel to the Slack Channels list.